Solve for $f(x)$ given that $f(x)=\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$
Let $y=f(x)$ be a real valued function and $f'(x)$ is continuous function such that $f'(x)\geq 0$ and $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$.
Solve the differential equation $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$$
My Attempt
Observe that $f(x)\geq 1$ and $f(x)=1$ is a solution.
The differential equation can be re-written as
$y=\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$
which gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=+\sqrt{y^2-1}$ since $f'(x)\geq 0$
$\Rightarrow \ln|f(x)+\sqrt{(f(x))^2-1}|=x+c$
Put $x=1$ to obtain $c=-1\Rightarrow \ln|f(x)+\sqrt{(f(x))^2-1}|=x-1$
$|f(x)+\sqrt{(f(x))^2-1}|=e^{x-1}\Rightarrow f(x)+\sqrt{(f(x))^2-1}=\pm e^{x-1}$
which on further solving gives
$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x-1}+e^{1-x})=\cosh (x-1)$ since $f(x)\geq 1$
$f(x)=
   \begin{cases} 
            1 &  x\leq 1, \\
      \text{cosh}\ \left(x-1\right) & x\geq 1. 
   \end{cases}$
But it is given that $f(0)=0$ which I feel should not have been given

My guess is that they meant $f'(0) = 0$ because $f(x) \geq 1$ for all $x$, like you showed.

So is  $f'(0)=0$ even required.

Yes, the condition $f(0) = 0$ seems to be an error, since it would imply $f'(0)^2 = -1$. By the way, you could have invoked an ansatz $f(x) = A\cosh(\omega(x-x_0))$ directly, because $f(x)^2 - f'(x)^2 = 1$ corresponds to the equation of a hyperbola.
